# Concrete steps sinking

Tags: concrete, outdoor, stairs

I’m wanting to raise my concrete steps. I noticed there is wood exposed where the steps would be aligned with the house. Do I need to cover the wood with anything before raising the steps?
Should there be any other steps I should take?
[image: sinking steps]

Comment: Theres a lot more wood behind the steps  Either the wood is treated or it isnt. Either way, theres not much you can do about it. Water will get to it.